# How to import category url key in different store views?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, import, url, stores

i have a website with more than 30 store views of different languages. My task is to translate the URL keys of categories for different store views. I can translate URL keys manually but as i just said i have more than 30 store views so it will be more feasible for me to import categories URL keys through csv file.
How can i achieve my task? Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can use Magento models, or you can use an import tool, for example FastSimpleImport which does the task much faster. 
You can use this code in any Magento script / model / controller:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        '_root' => 'RootCategoryName',
        '_category' => 'CategoryPath',
        'url_key' => 'urlkeydefault',
    ),
    array(
        '_store' => 'en',
        'url_key' => 'urlkeyen',
    ),
);

try {
    /** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */
    $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
    $import->processCategoryImport($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
}
```

Add more rows to the import with `_store`representing the store code and `url_key` representing the url key (surprise!)

Of course you have to include the FastSimpleImport module into your installation for that. Please see http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/categories.html for more details about category import, especially about the `_root` and `_category` parameters.